# inlineformset_factory - Django

Tags: html, mysql, python, banco-de-dados, django

Qual pode ser o motivo do `inlineformset_factory` não ter validado e salvo corretamente no banco de dados.

Tenho programado as seguintes partes até o momento;

VIEW:

```
def dev(request):
    form = modelFormDadosPessoais(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    endereco_formset = inlineformset_factory(dadosPessoais, enderecoContato, form=modelFormEnderecoContato, extra=1,can_delete=False)
    dependentes_formset =  inlineformset_factory(dadosPessoais, dependentes, form=modelFormDependentes, extra=1,can_delete=False)
    escolaridade_formset =  inlineformset_factory(dadosPessoais, escolaridade, form=modelFormEscolaridade, extra=1,can_delete=False)
    certificacao_formset =  inlineformset_factory(dadosPessoais, certificacao, form=modelFormCertificacao, extra=1,can_delete=False)
    profissional_formset =  inlineformset_factory(dadosPessoais, profissional, form=modelFormProfissional, extra=1,can_delete=False)
    dadosBancarios_formset =  inlineformset_factory(dadosPessoais, dadosBancarios, form=modelFormDadosBancarios, extra=1,can_delete=False)
    outros_formset =  inlineformset_factory(dadosPessoais, outros, form=ModelFormOutros, extra=1,can_delete=False)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            novo_usuario = form.save()
            endereco_form = endereco_formset(request.POST, instance=novo_usuario)
            dependentes_form = dependentes_formset(request.POST, instance=novo_usuario)
            escolaridade_form = escolaridade_formset(request.POST, instance=novo_usuario)
            certificacao_form = certificacao_formset(request.POST, instance=novo_usuario)
            profissional_form = profissional_formset(request.POST, instance=novo_usuario)
            dadosBancarios_form = dadosBancarios_formset(request.POST, instance=novo_usuario)
            outros_form = outros_formset(request.POST, instance=novo_usuario)
            
            print(endereco_form)


            if endereco_form.is_valid() and dependentes_form.is_valid() and escolaridade_form.is_valid() and certificacao_form.is_valid() and profissional_form.is_valid() and dadosBancarios_form.is_valid() and outros_form.is_valid():
                endereco_form.save()
                dependentes_form.save()
                escolaridade_form.save()
                certificacao_form.save()
                profissional_form.save()
                dadosBancarios_form.save()
                outros_form.save()
                

                return HttpResponse('Salvo ')
            
    else:
        endereco_form = endereco_formset(instance=dadosPessoais())
        dependentes_form = dependentes_formset(instance=dadosPessoais())
        escolaridade_form = escolaridade_formset(instance=dadosPessoais())
        certificacao_form = certificacao_formset(instance=dadosPessoais())
        profissional_form = profissional_formset(instance=dadosPessoais())
        dadosBancarios_form = dadosBancarios_formset(instance=dadosPessoais())
        outros_form = outros_formset(instance=dadosPessoais())

    context = {
        'dados': form,
        'endereco_form': endereco_form,
        'dependentes_form': dependentes_form,
        'escolaridade_form': escolaridade_form,
        'certificacao_form': certificacao_form,
        'profissional_form': profissional_form,
        'dadosBancarios_form': dadosBancarios_form,
        'outros_form': outros_form}
    
    return render(request, 'ccis/dev.html',context)
```

Somente um dos formulários, os outras estão iguais:

HTML :

```
  <code>  {{ dependentes_form.management_form }}
          <div class="row pt-5">
            <hr>
            <h5>Dependentes</h5>
            
            {%for d in dependentes_form%}
            
            
            <div class="col-6">
                <label class="form-label">Nome Completo:</label>
                {{d.nomeCompleto }} 
            </div>

            <div class="col-3">
                <label class="form-label">CPF:</label>
                {{d.cpf}}
            </div>

            <div class="col-3">
                <label class="form-label">Nascimento:</label>
                {{d.dataNascimento}}
            </div>

            <div class="col-3">
                <label class="form-label">Relação:</label>
                {{d.relacao}}
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <label class="form-label">Email:</label>
                {{d.email}}
            </div>

            <div class="col-3">
                <label class="form-label">Contato:</label>
                {{d.contato}}
            </div>
        </div>  
        {% endfor%}  </code>
```

Answer (score -1):

O código apresentado é uma **view** de uma página de formulário com vários formulários relacionados usando o **inlineformset_factory** do Django. Os formulários estão sendo exibidos na página HTML e, quando o **formulário** é **enviado**, ele é **validado** e **salvo** no banco de dados.

No exemplo apresentado, um dos formulários é exibido usando o loop for, que é usado para iterar através de cada um dos dependentes do usuário. Dentro do loop, são exibidos os campos de cada dependente usando tags HTML e as variáveis ​​dos formulários dependentes são exibidas usando a **interpolação** de string do **Django** (por **exemplo**, **{{ d.nomeCompleto }}**).

No entanto, o código **não mostra nenhum erro específico** que possa estar ocorrendo no momento da validação e salvamento dos formulários, o que dificulta a identificação do problema. **Para depurar esse problema, seria necessário examinar os logs de erros e verificar se há algum erro específico sendo retornado**.